# Combining two lists which do not have same numbers of entries

Tags: python

I have following two lists to combine. I'm trying to use `zip()` but header_list runs out for obvious reason.

```
header_list = ['1 mo', '3 mo', '6 mo', '1 yr', '2 yr', '3 yr', '5 yr', '7
yr', '10 yr', '20 yr', '30 yr']

data_list = [1.29, 1.44, 1.61, 1.83, 1.92, 2.01, 2.25, 2.38, 2.46,
2.64, 2.81, 1.29, 1.41, 1.59, 1.81, 1.94, 2.02, 2.25, 2.37, 2.44, 2.62, 2.78, 1.28, 1.41, 1.6, 1.82, 1.96, 2.05, 2.27, 2.38, 2.46, 2.62, 2.79]
```

The result should be a tuple in the following format:

```
('1 mo', 1.29)
('3 mo', 1.44)
('6 mo', 1.61)
('1 yr', 1.83)
('2 yr', 1.92)
('3 yr', 2.01)
('5 yr', 2.25)
('7 yr', 2.38)
('10 yr', 2.46)
('20 yr', 2.64)
('30 yr', 2.81)
('1 mo', 1.29)
('3 mo', 1.41)
('6 mo', 1.59)
('1 yr', 1.81)
('2 yr', 1.94)
('3 yr', 2.02)
('5 yr', 2.25)
('7 yr', 2.37)
('10 yr', 2.44)
('20 yr', 2.62)
('30 yr', 2.78)
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use itertools you can use [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat the shorter one:

```
from itertools import cycle
print(zip(cycle(header_list), data_list))
```

`zip` will stop once the shorter iterable ends. `cycle` returns an iterable that never ends (constantly repeats `header_list`), so `data_list` will be shorter (and it will stop zipping when `data_list` ends).

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `cycle` function, thanks for this!

Comment: Awesome, does the job. Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the shorter list to simply wrap, you can iterate over the indices of the longer list and mod the current index by the length of the shorter list:

```
out = [(header_list[i%len(header_list)], data_list[i]) for i in range(len(data_list))]
```

Or, to be more Pythonic:

```
out = [(header_list[i%len(header_list)], e) for i,e in enumerate(data_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this work fine.

Comment: Instead of iterating over `range(len(data_list))`, I'd contend the more python way would be to iterate over `enumerate(data_list)`. List indices are generally less pythonic.

Comment: @BaileyParker Thanks, added as an option

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
counter = 0
new_list = []
for data in data_list:
    new_list.append([header_list[counter%len(header_list)],data])
    counter+=1
```

Comment: In general, using counters and `list.append` isn't very pythonic. In this instance, you'd definitely be better off constructing the list via a comprehension. If you do need to access an index, `enumerate` is your friend.

Comment: @BaileyParker `list.append` is *perfectly pythonic*, although you are correct, here `enumerate` is what you would use instead of a counter variable. Better yet, though, it would be `zip`